# With custom UserNamePasswordValidator, can I kill the user's WPF "session"?

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I'm using a custom UserNamePasswordValidator, which instantiates and logs in to our internal API.

This API exposes an event that's fired when the user is "kicked" (by another administrative user), and I'd like to respond to this by killing the WCF session, so that further calls throw an exception.

How do I go about doing this?

My WCF service is hosted in a Windows service (not IIS). Instantiating and logging in to the internal API takes quite a long time, so I can't do it on every service call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some code at http://www.neovolve.com/post/2008/04/07/wcf-security-getting-the-password-of-the-user.aspx that shows how to use a custom `ServiceCredentials` class and, from there, passing the user's details all the way through to `Thread.CurrentPrinciple`.

Starting from that code, I've stashed the Connection object in a custom principal object, which means that I can get to it in a session context. Then, I added a custom `CodeAccessSecurityAttribute` that checks that connection object to see if it's been disconnected. If it has, an exception is thrown, which kills the user's session.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect that service will authenticate each user call with user name and password than you can have any code in your validator. But if you expect using per session service instancing you will probably also use security context (security session). In that case only first request is authenticated by validator and subsequent request are authenticated by token generated during establishing security context.

**Edit:**

Each running service is represented by InstanceContext class. If you have PerSession services the InstanceContext is same for each call. If you store reference to InstanceContext somewhere you should be able to release instance and close session - I have never tryed but it should be possible.

Comment: I'm using per-session instancing, because logging in to our API is expensive. Question remains: how do I revoke the session?

Comment: Which binding do you use? PerSession instancing is dependent on some other session type - transport, security or reliable.

Comment: Whichever binding I'll need to: I control the client and the server.